# PHP foreach shows last record in first iteration

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I have the following code in my view :

```
@foreach($totalUsers as $user)
    <tr>
        <td class="v-a-m ">
            <input type="checkbox" class="user" name="user" value="{{$user->id}}">
            <input type="hidden" name="city" value="{{$user->city}}">
        </td>
        <td class="v-a-m text-white">
            <span>{{$user->name}}</span>
        </td>
        <td class="v-a-m">
            <span>{{$user->cnic}}</span>
        </td>
   </tr>
@endforeach
```

Some Jquery :

```
$('input.user').on('change', function() {
    $('input.user').not(this).prop('checked', false);
});
```

The `hidden field` is not returning its `iteration` result, Instead it **returns the result of the last row in the database table.**

`dd($request->all());` return the requests, but `city` have the value of last row of the table, Which is well tested.

**What i want is that the `hidden` field should return the current iteration city.**

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: You using the relationship with city method?

Comment: Could you inspect the actual html from your browser and check what is the value actually rendered in your form?

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can't have multiple input fields with the same name.

If you are passing an user `id` to the controller, Or anything where you can query the users table with, There you can get the city of the exact same user, Whom you checked the checkbox.

Like :

```
public function findUser(Request $request){
    //You can pass anything here with `where()`, E.g name,username
    $user = \App\User::find($request->get('id'));

    //Do the rest...
}
```

You should use `first()` with eloquent `where()`

Answer (score 0):

If you need your user to select one of the options, you need to replace your `checkbox` with `radio` button.
With that, only one option will be allowed to be selected.

CSS and JS can help you hiding the city radio and making it synced with the user radio:

```
@foreach($totalUsers as $user)
    <tr>
        <td class="v-a-m">
            <label class="user-label">
                <input type="radio" class="user-radio" name="user" value="{{ $user->id }}"/>
                {{ $user->id }}
            </label>
            <input type="radio" class="city-radio" name="city" value="{{ $user->city }}"/>
        </td>
        <td class="v-a-m text-white">
            <span>{{ $user->name }}</span>
        </td>
        <td class="v-a-m">
            <span>{{ $user->cnic }}</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach

<style>
    .city-radio {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.user-label').change(function () {
            $(this).parent().find('.city-radio').prop("checked", true);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Your code gives me all the cities, Where i need one which is selected by clicking the checkbox.

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what do you try to do? What the user needs to check, and what you expect to get on your server?

Comment: I have a table inside a form, Each row of the html table have checkbox, By clicking on a checkbox i should get the data of the selected row in server. Current situation is that i do get the selected row data on server but along that the hidden field have data from the last row of the DB table .

Comment: So you expect to get a list of cities which their checkbox were checked?

Comment: I can select only one checkbox from the list. I cannot select many.

Comment: And yes the selected checkbox value should come up.

Comment: And the value of the user & city should be sent? Or just the city?

Comment: Both of them should come up, where both are coming, But city have ambiguous value.

Comment: Can we make hidden the name="city" field ? Because its need hidden.

Comment: I was using jquery .I have updated the question. Please have a look

Comment: I see, but hidden field cannot be checked / uncheck, therefore it will be always sent to the server. I've updated the code for you need - check it out

Answer (score 0):

You could "disable/enable" the city you want to send with the user input to "allow/prevent" the hidden field from submitting to the server, in your change event like :

```
$('input.user').on('change', function() {
   $('input.user').not(this).attr('selected', false);
   $('input.city').attr('disabled','disabled');

   $(this).siblings('input.city').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

You could see that just the related city with selected user will be send in the submit action.

Hope this helps.

```js
$('input.user').on('change', function() {
   $('input.user').not(this).attr('selected', false);
   $('input.city').attr('disabled','disabled');

   $(this).siblings('input.city').removeAttr('disabled');
});

$(document).on('submit','form.remember',function(e){
   console.log($(this).serialize());
   return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="remember">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="v-a-m ">
        <input type="radio" name="user" class="user" value="1" />
        <input type="hidden" name="city" class="city" value="city_1" disabled />
      </td>
      <td class="v-a-m text-white"><span>name 1</span></td>
      <td class="v-a-m"><span>cnic 1</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="v-a-m ">
        <input type="radio" name="user" class="user" value="2" />
        <input type="hidden" name="city" class="city" value="city_2" disabled />
      </td>
      <td class="v-a-m text-white"><span>name 2</span></td>
      <td class="v-a-m"><span>cnic 2</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="v-a-m ">
        <input type="radio" name="user" class="user" value="3" />
        <input type="hidden" name="city" class="city" value="city_3" disabled />
      </td>
      <td class="v-a-m text-white"><span>name 3</span></td>
      <td class="v-a-m"><span>cnic 3</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="v-a-m ">
        <input type="radio" name="user" class="user" value="4"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="city" class="city" value="city_4" disabled />
      </td>
      <td class="v-a-m text-white"><span>name 4</span></td>
      <td class="v-a-m"><span>cnic 4</span></td>
    </tr>
  </table> 
  
  <input type="submit" value="Submit values"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But the city field gives me all the cities in array.

Comment: I am not accessing any relationships. The data comes from controller to view, I simply parse the data. There is no relationship involved.

Comment: Are you using jQuery in you project ?

Comment: Yes, I have updated the question. Please have a look

Answer (score 0):

Your form can't have multiple input fields with the same name. It works with the checkbox because it's stores the value in an array with the same name. But input type hidden will return the value of the last input of the form with the same name, which is the last row of your table. In other word, the value is overwritten by the last input field.

when you use `city[]`, it will return an array of all cities, which is not what you want.

I'dont understand your purpose of including hidden field with the user's city. Couldn't you just retrieve this data from your controller?

```
foreach($request->user as $user) {
    $user->city // and do your login here. 
}
```

Comment: Checkboxes don't return an array either unless you explicitly use [] notation in the checkbox field name